# Attaching event handling to menus and buttons

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-8

I am using IE8. Thus request to put solutions which work on IE8.

The problem is age old. I have a big form in the jsp. User fills the form. Mistakenly presses the backspace on a uneditable textbox and the data entered is all lost.

To warn the user, I wrote the following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
     return "Your work will be lost."; 
};
```

However, now this alert comes for all the links, menus and buttons as well along with the backspace key press even though the page unload is valid in these cases.

I solved it for the hyperlinks by calling a function on onclick event:

```
var link_was_clicked = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    if(link_was_clicked){
        return;
    }
    return "Your work will be lost."; 
}; 

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
        link_was_clicked = true;
    }
}
```

This works as expected.

However, I do not know how to do the same for the menus and the buttons on the page.

I am using Array as a menu:

```
var menus = new Array();
menus[0] = new menu( .. and so on
```

Item getting added to the menu as:

```
menus[0].addItem("javascript:loadMyHome();", "", 65, "left", "&nbsp;MyHome", 0);
```

The `loadMyHome()` is having submit:

```
document.myFormName.submit();
```

Similarly, the buttons are defined as:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="MyButton"  onClick="funcMyButton()" />
```

The `funcMyButton()` also has submit:

```
document.myFormName.submit();
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

For the backspace key, why not include a `window.addEventListener("keydown",onKeyDown,false);` Then later in your code have the function: `function onKeyDown(e) { if(e.keyCode == 8) do blah;` 8 is the char code for the backspace key. Similarily, If you want to do the same for other elements of a webpage, use objects. For instance: `Object.Menu1 = document.getElementById('menuId');` Then: `Object.Menu1.addEventListener("keydown",onKeyDown,false);` Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be to trigger the alert when backspace is pressed and no text field currently is in focus.

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 8 && document.activeElement.type !== 'text') {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Your work will be lost.');
    }
});
```

**With IE8 support (untested):**

JS:

```
var _win = window;

if (_win.addEventListener) {
    _win.addEventListener('keydown', showWarning, false);
} else {
    _win.attachEvent('keydown', showWarning);
}

function showWarning(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 8 && document.activeElement.type !== 'text') {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Your work will be lost.');
    }
});
```

Comment: addEventListener does not work in IE8. I need a solution which works with IE8.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I wasn't able to test the code. Have you been able to try it out in IE8?